# python requests.get not return complete result

Tags: python, python-requests

It doesn't return complete result when I use requests.get to get some websites' titles.
my code:

```
import requests
url="http://114.54.23.46"
res=requests.get(url)
print res.content
```

result:

```
'\n\n<!doctype html>\n<meta name="description" content="\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe5\xb8\x90\xe5\x8f\xb7\xe8\x83\xbd\xe4\xbd\xbf\xe7\x94\xa8\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe6\x89\x8b\xe6\x9c\xba\xef\xbc\x8cMIUI\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe4\xba\x91\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xa4\x9a\xe7\x9c\x8b\xe9\x98\x85\xe8\xaf\xbb\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe8\x81\x8a\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe7\xa4\xbe\xe5\x8c\xba\xe7\xad\x89\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe6\x9c\x8d\xe5\x8a\xa1\xe3\x80\x82" />\n<meta name="keywords" content="\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe5\xb8\x90\xe5\x8f\xb7\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe8\xb4\xa6\xe5\x8f\xb7\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe6\xb3\xa8\xe5\x86\x8c\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\xb3\xa8\xe5\x86\x8c\xef\xbc\x8cMi Account\xef\xbc\x8cSign in\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb8\x90\xe5\x8f\xb7\xef\xbc\x8c\xe8\xb4\xa6\xe5\x8f\xb7\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe5\xb8\x90\xe6\x88\xb7\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x99\xbb\xe5\xbd\x95\xef\xbc\x8c\xe7\x99\xbb\xe9\x99\x86\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xae\x89\xe5\x85\xa8\xe4\xbb\xa4\xe7\x89\x8c\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\x8a\xa8\xe6\x80\x81\xe5\x8f\xa3\xe4\xbb\xa4\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\xb1\xb3\xe6\xb3\xa8\xe5\x86\x8c\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\x89\xbe\xe5\x9b\x9e\xe5\xaf\x86\xe7\xa0\x81" />\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n  \n\n\n\n\n  \n    \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n      \n\n  \n\n
<script>\nvar LANG=(function(){\n    var locale=("zh_CN").toLowerCase();\n    if(locale){\n      if(locale.indexOf("en")>-1){\n        return {data:"en",cls:"en"};\n      }else if(locale.indexOf("zh")>-1){\n        if(locale.indexOf("cn")===-1){\n          return {data:"tw",cls:"zh_TW"};\n        }else{\n          return {data:"cn",cls:"zh_CN"};\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    return {data:"en",cls:"en"};\n})();\n</script>\n\n
<script>\nvar _d_={};\nvar _t_={\n  statURL:\'https://data.mistat.xiaomi.com/mistats\',\n  appId:"2882303761517246742",\n  appKey:"5621724658742",\n  jspcomplete:(new Date()).getTime(),\n  supportLocalstorage:!!window.localStorage,\n  samplingBase:100,\n  samplingRate:5\n};\nif(window.performance){\n  var timing=performance.timing;\n  if(!timing.responseEnd){\n    timing.responseEnd=timing.responseStart;\n  }\n  _d_.startTS=timing.fetchStart\n  _d_.endTS=timing.responseEnd;\n}else{\n  _d_.startTS=_d_.endTS=(new Date()).getTime();\n}\nvar JSP_VAR={\n  deviceType:\'PC\',\n  dataCenter:\'hh\',\n  locale:"zh_CN",\n  region:"CN",\n  callback:"http://vip.miliao.com/sts?sign=OX%2BrnFCklhTx9DnnvktkM%2F7lESo%3D&followup=http%3A%2F%2F114.54.23.46%2F",\n  sid:"vip.miliao.com",\n  qs:"%3Fcallback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fvip.miliao.com%252Fsts%253Fsign%253DOX%25252BrnFCklhTx9DnnvktkM%25252F7lESo%25253D%2526followup%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252F114.54.23.46%25252F%26sid%3Dvip.miliao.com",\n  hidden:"",\n  "_sign":"2im3EnAZlcYBLXzg7BUeCCx0ulU=",\n  serviceParam :\'{"checkSafePhone":false}\',\n 
 privacyLink:\'http://www.miui.com/res/doc/privacy/cn.html\'\n};\nvar PAGE_VAR={\n  form_cache:false,\n  cache_key:(JSP_VAR.deviceType!=="mobile" ? "/static/res/1a91f87/account-static/html/login/dist/v2/login-cn.html" : "/static/res/1a91f87/account-static/html/login/dist/v2/login-wap-cn.html")\n};\nif(location.search.indexOf("_debugMode")>-1){\n  window.localStorage && window.localStorage.removeItem(PAGE_VAR.cache_key);\n}\n(function(){\n  function getLocal(url){\n    if(window.localStorage){\n      var data=localStorage.getItem(url);\n      return data;\n    }\n    return null;\n  }\n  function setLocal(url,data){\n    if(window.localStorage && data){\n      try{\n        localStorage.setItem(url,data);\n      }catch(e){}\n    }\n  }\n  function getContent(url){\n    var xhr= new (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject)("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");\n    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {\n      
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {\n          setLocal(url,xhr.responseText);\n          _t_.htmlGetEnd=(new Date()).getTime();\n          document.write(xhr.responseText);\n          document.close();\n      }\n    };\n    xhr.open("GET",url,false);\n    xhr.send();\n  }\n  var cache_key=PAGE_VAR.cache_key;\n      _t_.version=cache_key;\n  var html=getLocal(cache_key);\n  if(html){\n    _t_.htmlCache=true;\n    PAGE_VAR.form_cache=true;\n    document.write(html);\n    document.close();\n  }else{\n    _t_.htmlCache=false;\n    _t_.htmlGetStart=(new Date()).getTime();\n    getContent(cache_key);\n  }\n})();\n</script>\n'
```

but when I use browser to visit this website, the source code is much longer than the result. 
why and how can I fix this problem? thanks!

Comment: I suspect that site implements javascript for delivering content- where `requests` only works for non-javascript created contents so try `selenium` etc.

Comment: The result is complete; that's the sum total of the response you can get on that URL. Your browser fetches *more data* based on this content however. You'll have to do the same.